# Prove that, if $A, B \in M_{m × n}(K)$ then $A$ is equivalent to $I^{m, n}_r \iff rank(A)=r$, and $A$ is equivalent to $B$ iff their ranks are equal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, solution-verification, matrix-rank

Given this proposition

> Let $f: U → V$ be a linear function. Then there exists basis of $U$ and $V$ such that the matrix associated with f is of the form
>   $$
> \pmatrix{I_r & 0\\0 & 0}
> $$
>   where $I_r$ is identity matrix and r is the range of $f$.

Show that

> Let $I^{m, n}_r$ be a $m\times n$ matrix whose first $r$ lines are the canonical base of $K^r$ and whose remaining lines are zero, i.e., 
>   $$
> I^{m, n}_r = \pmatrix{I_r & 0\\0 & 0}
> $$ Prove that, if $A, B \in M_{m × n}(K)$ then $A$ is equivalent to $I^{m, n}_r \iff rank(A)=r$. Prove that $A$ is equivalent to $B$ iff their ranks are equal.

My attempt:

$\Rightarrow$
Let A be a matrix associated to a linear transformation $T:U\rightarrow V$, then, by the proposition, there exists basis of $U$ and $V$ such that 
$$
A =\pmatrix{I_r & 0\\0 & 0}
$$
where $I_r$ is identity matrix and $rank(T)=r \implies rank(A)=r$.

$\Leftarrow$
We know that $rank(A)=r \implies \exists$ a linear transformation $T:U\rightarrow V$ s.t. $rank(T)=r$, so by the proposition, there exists basis of $U$ and $V$ such that 
$$
A =\pmatrix{I_r & 0\\0 & 0}
$$
So clearly A is equivalent to $I^{m, n}_r$

Now, to prove that $A$ is equivalent to $B$ iff their ranks are equal, just make $B = I^{m, n}_r$

Is it right?

Comment: Your proof for the first statement is perfect.  I have no clue what you're trying to say in your proof for the second statement, so it is at the very least insufficiently explained.

Comment: Well, I was thinking that you can consider the same $A$ as the first statement and $B = I^{m, n}_r$, but I think that is a particular case.

Comment: Yes: that is indeed a particular case, so it doesn't address the question being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The key to the second part is to observe that if $A$ is equivalent to $C$ and $C$ is equivalent to $B$, then $A$ is equivalent to $B$.

Comment: This can be concisely (albeit confusingly) stated as "matrix equivalence is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)".

Comment: Okay, but what happens with the rank?

Comment: @Mystery Once you estalbish this statement, take $C = I^{m,n}_r$ as your intermediate matrix